# Gridview row update/insert from textbox when edit button is clicked

Tags: asp.net, gridview, panel

I have two panels.In panel1 i have a registration form

like username,password,email,city,state,zip

and in panel2 I have gridview.I am inserting the data into sql server database from the registration form and I am binding the data to gridview.
when edit button click in the gridview I am hiding the panel2 that is gridview and I am getting the values from gridview to textboxes in the registration form.When I am modifying the data in the registration form and when button is clicked the data is not updated in the gridview row,as well as new row is adding in the database and it is binding to the gridview

help me how to do this task

Comment: Check you have added IsPostback property at page load. try to debug it if you're getting data at code behind.

Comment: Seems there is a problem in your query you are using to update data.
I think you are calling the same function that you call while doing registration(i.e. record insertion), Do you have two different buttons in panel1 for registration and edit information?

Answer (score 0):

first retrieve the unique id of the data row you want to edit from your table using following method:

```
protected void GridView_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{

      string id_For_Edit = GridView.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[0].Text;
}
```

and then update the data for that particular row...

```
query= "update table_name set column_name= 'value' where unique_column = 'id_For_Edit'
```